# Why was this post closed as offtopic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

I have no clue as to why the following post was closed as 'off-topic'.

[Audio amplifier kills FM radios signal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34854/audio-amplifier-kills-fm-radios-signal)

Also, wouldn't it be better if the moderators can leave a little bit of detail with a comment on why exactly it was closed rather than just leaving it to the canned message like 'off topic' etc..

Comment: Did you read our [faq]? Also, there are links to the faq and info about closed questions in the [closed] description.

Comment: @CamilStaps Of course I did. But it would be much better if the mods can highlight the part of FAQ that was in violation for a particular post.

Comment: Nah, in most cases it's clear. Otherwise, you can ask a meta question, ask in the comments, or in the chat. But most of the time it's perfectly clear.

Answer (score 2):

It was closed as off topic because the OP mentioned consumer products (which isn't a good reason in the first place). But the closed message already has details why, it points to the FAQ, first question being What kind of questions are welcomed here:

> but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific electronics design problem
> - the theory and simulation of
>     electromagnetic forces
> - a communication scheme
> - the writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - a shopping or buying recommendation
> - consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart phones, except when designing these products **or modifying their electronics for other uses**
> - Programming software for a PC
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Bolded part is my problem with a question like that being closed. It specifically wanted to modify the radio to work without a headphone cable.

Comment: The question at one part asked 'how to hack the setup to get a stronger signal' etc.. won't this fall under 'modifying their electronics' ?

Comment: @Power-Inside That is what I am saying. It should not have been closed.

Answer (score 2):

The point made about mods or close-voters providing a bit of insight into the reason for closing, at least as a learning aid to new members, is valid, and a very positive habit if only we could inculcate it among our established members.

I agree with this particular question being closed, for the very reasons ably described by others here, however.

Answer (score -2):

I was one of those that voted to close.  After reading the first few lines, it was clear this was a consumer electronics question, not a electrical engineering question.

Sometimes I leave a comment, sometimes not.  This particular one was a long time ago, and I don't remember this question specifically.  Reasons not to leave a comment that could apply here include that it should be obvious, that engaging the OP in discussion about closing would likely just yield pointless arguing, and that there is really nothing for the OP to fix to make a useful question appropriate for here.

My impression reading the question just now is that this guy never bothered to read the guidelines and just dumped his question on us.  If they can't be bothered to read the rules before posting, I don't see the point bothing to explain why the post is being closed.  This is not the kind of person likely to add any long term value to the site, so a unceremonious boot out the door is the most expedient solution.

Comment: The premise that consumer electronics and engineering are mutually exclusive is inherently flawed.  It's also quite counterproductive to engineering education, since your more capable engineers tend to be those who expressed curiosity about the functioning of consumer products before embarking on their formal training.  Instead of a teachable moment about how an Engineer approaches a problem (especially one where full documentation is not available), it becomes simply a total rejection of a person.